# Django template - convert datetime format to string

Tags: django, datetime, django-templates

I need to convert datetime format to string in Django template:

`<input name="wtn_datetime" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" value="{{ wtn.wtn_datetime }}">`

what is the best way to get string in `value="{{ wtn.wtn_datetime }}`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the [**`|date`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
value="{{ wtn.wtn_datetime|date:'d/m/Y H:i' }}"
```

For example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> Template("{{ foo|date:'d/m/Y H:i' }}").render(Context({'foo': timezone.now()}))
'19/02/2021 21:52'
```

But often it is not a good idea to manually make your own forms. Normally this is done by defining a widget that explains how to render a form element.